# Identifying if object[1] has a value?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there any way that I can identify if a part of my table/array contains a value

example

Table: object = {
a,
b,
c,
d,
e
}

now I would like to know if object[1] does contain a value?

especially if my table is continuously being incremented

is "object[1].hasValue" code exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In lua, a table not having a value for some key, is the same as the value at the key being nil. So you can just write

```
if object[1]~=nil then
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly check it, with condition like below:

```
if( object[1] ) then
    print("has value");
else
    print("nil");
end
```

Comment: not substantial, but in this answer all of the semicolons and round braces can be omitted

Comment: problem with this approach is that when object[1] contains a `false` it will fail